# Why does my for-loop code in javascript only run once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, browser, playwright

I have no idea why the for-loop only run once.
My intention is making the code run through all elements in `foodGroupIdsOnPage1`.
But it only runs through the first element now.

Could anyone please explain to me? Thank you for your help in advance.

```
async function initialize() {
    const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const context = await browser.newContext();                        ////create a new browser context, which means no cookies and cache saved
    const tab1 = await context.newPage();
    return { tab1, context };
}

async function GotoPage2() {     ////wait for function>>>only run the next command after all the commands inside the next bracket run

    const page1_foodGroupButton = id.querySelector('a')         ////beginning of the for loop
    await page1_foodGroupButton.click();
};

async function main() {

    const { tab1, context } = await initialize();

    await tab1.goto('https://www.cfs.gov.hk/tc_chi/nutrient/search1.php');

    const foodGroupIdsOnPage1 = await tab1.evaluate(async function getFoodGroupsOnPage1() {

        return [...document.querySelector('.tableResponsive').querySelectorAll('td ')].map(e => e.id);

    })

    for (let id of foodGroupIdsOnPage1) {

        await tab1.evaluate(id => {

            const page1_foodGroupButton = document.querySelector('[id=' + `"${id}"` + ']').querySelector('a')         ////beginning of the for loop
            page1_foodGroupButton.click();

        }, id);

        await tab1.waitForTimeout(2000);
        await tab1.click('[id^=grp] > a');

        await tab1.waitForTimeout(2000);
        const ArrayOfTabs = context.pages();   ////get how many tabs chromium are

        let tab2 = ArrayOfTabs[1];              ////make active tab to the second tab
        await tab2.evaluate(async function extractFoodGroupData() {
            let tableOfAllFoods = [];
            let rowsOnPage3 = document.querySelector(".colorTable2").querySelectorAll("tr");
            for (let row_OnPage3 of rowsOnPage3) {
                let arrayNutritionOfOneFood = [];
                let cellsInOneRow = row_OnPage3.querySelectorAll("td");
                for (let cell of cellsInOneRow) {
                    arrayNutritionOfOneFood.push(cell.innerText);
                }

                tableOfAllFoods.push(arrayNutritionOfOneFood);
            }

        });
        tab2.close();
        tab1.goBack();
        return;

    }

}

main();
```

Comment: Could it be the return statement at the bottom of the loops scope?

Comment: What do you mean by "it"? the reason why my code breaks?

I am a very beginner. Do you hava any idea how to fix? Thanks Paul.

Comment: Yes by **it** I mean the problem you have. To put it another way. Could the reason it stops after the first iteration of the loop be the `return` statement? The one after `tab1.goBack();`? That would not only exit the loop but the whole `main` function.

Comment: Your `return` statement inside the `for` loop exits the loop and the function at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.

The first problem is that `return` terminates the iteration. So delete it.

The second problem is that the second iteration cycle runs before
`tab1.goBack();`

Simply add `await` before `tab1.goBack();` to fix the second problem.